# How do you display only the first paragraph or define an excerpt in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

I've prepared this post

```
---
layout: post
tags:
- tag1
title: Post Title 1
categories:
- category1
---

Excerpt for post 1    

<!-- More -->

Body of post 1
```

I'm using `{{ post.excerpt }}` and in _config.yml have set

```
excerpt_separator: "<!-- more -->"
```

But on the page it's still displaying both the excerpt and body text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see the difference :

```
<!-- More --> != <!-- more -->
```

Comment: I think I have a welt on my forehead from hitting myself in the head so hard. ;) thanks

Answer (score 5):

How about this

`{{ post.content | strip_html | truncatewords: 50 }}`

Comment: I was a little skeptical that this would be too hacky, but after trying it, it looks quite good.